# loadUserByUsername overrides nothing in springboot authentication

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, microservices

> I am new to microservice. I want to access username(email)and password
> from another service  which is userregistration service. when I create
> a authentication service and try to access  email password I am
> getting compile time error.

```
e: E:\Nil Projects\NewMicroService\security-service\src\main\kotlin\com\security\securityservice\service\JwtUserDetailsService.kt: (16, 5): 'loadUserByUsername' overrides nothing
```

> Here is the my codes
> jwtuserdetailsservice.kt

```
package com.security.securityservice.service

import com.security.securityservice.UserRepository
import com.security.securityservice.entity.User
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class JwtUserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userDTO:UserRepository

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun loadUserByUsername(email: String?): UserDetails {
       val user: User =userDTO.findUserByEmail(email)
        if (userDTO == null){
            UsernameNotFoundException("your email id doesn't exist" + email)
        }
        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.userId.email,user.userId.password,ArrayList())
    }


}
```

> Above i define user.userId.email and user.userId.password because I
> define userId in my User.kt . this userId comes from
> userRegistration-service, this id holds username and password, but I
> am not able to access email and password in authentication servicie I
> am getting error at this particular point "return
> org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.userId.email,user.userId.password,ArrayList())"
>
> User.kt

```
package com.security.securityservice.entity

import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue
import javax.persistence.GenerationType
import javax.persistence.Id

@Entity
data class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    val userAuthId:Long=-1,
    val otp:Int=0,
    val token:String="",
    var userId:Long=-1,
)
```

> ResponseTemplate.kt

```
package com.security.securityservice.VO

import com.security.securityservice.entity.User

data class ResponseTemplate(
    val user:User?=null,
    val userRegistration: UserRegistration?=null,
)
```

> UserRegistration.kt

```
package com.security.securityservice.VO

data class UserRegistration(
    val userId:Long=-1,
    val firstName:String="",
    val lastName:String="",
    val email:String="",
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with microservice instead with simple OOPs programming.
When you say the child class `override` certain behaviour then it must have one before, which in your case is None. Looking closely at the definition of the class `JwtUserDetailsService` there is no parent class/neither any interface present hence there is nothing to override. So line

```
override fun loadUserByUsername(email: String?): UserDetails {
```

will never compile. I think you should be implementing* the interface here to provide the behaviour `UserDetailsService`. You see that `loadUserByUsername` comes from the interface `User`DetailsService
Now the code may compile but in order to make authentication work correctly, you have to properly integrate with the authentication manager.